# Reduce the number of rows in a dataframe based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which consists of 9821 rows and one column. The values in it are listed in groups of 161 produced 61 times (161X61=9821). I need to reduce the number of rows to 9660 (161X60=9660) by replacing the first 2 values of each group of 161 into an average of those 2 values. In more simple words, in my existing dataframe the following groups of indexes (0, 1), (61, 62) ... (9760, 9761) need to be averaged in order to get a new dataframe with 9660 rows. Any ideas?

this is what I have (groups of 4 produced 3 times - 4X3=12):

> 0  10
>
> 1  11
>
> 2  12
>
> 3  13
>
> 4  14
>
> 5  15
>
> 6  16
>
> 7  17
>
> 8  18
>
> 9  19
>
> 10 20
>
> 11 21

this is what I want (groups of 3 produced 3 times - 3X3=9):

> 0  10.5
>
> 1  12
>
> 2  13
>
> 3  14.5
>
> 4  16
>
> 5  17
>
> 6  18.5
>
> 7  20
>
> 8  21

Comment: It would be nice if you could paste your data and the expected output. This is not very easy to understand.

Comment: Please provide a small set of sample data as text that we can copy and paste. Include the corresponding desired result. Check out the guide on [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/3620003).

Comment: tried my best to create an example!

Comment: Can you please explain how you are averaging in order to arrive at the numbers in the expected output?

Comment: No problem, I apologize for the confusion caused. In the data I provided the whole data can be divided into 3 separate groups with 4 rows in each group. So what i need to do is to average the first 2 rows of each group, thus arriving at 3 separate groups with 3 rows in each group.

Comment: Could you make an example? E.g. 10.5 is calculated as follows and 18.5 is calculated as follows: ...

Comment: 10.5 = (10+11)/2, 14.5 = (14+15)/2, 18.5 = (18+19)/2

Comment: OK but your next number is 12, but neither (11 + 12)/2 = 12 nor (12 + 13)/2 = 12.

Comment: yes exactly, my first group is 10, 11, 12, 13 and i need only first 2 rows to be averaged and get 10.5, 12, 13. my second group is 14, 15, 16, 17 and i should get 14.5, 16, 17 (again only first 2 rows of the group are averaged) and so on.

Comment: Ah! I understand it now.

Comment: Sorry! wasn't sure how to properly word what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not super happy with this answer but I'm putting it out there for review.

```
>>> df[df.index%4 == 0] = df.groupby(df.index//4).apply(lambda s: s.iloc[:2].mean()).values
>>> df = df[:-3]
>>> df
      0
0  10.5
1  11.0
2  12.0
3  13.0
4  14.5
5  15.0
6  16.0
7  17.0
8  18.5
```

Comment: Worked for that example I gave, but didn't work for my real data for some reason. Thanks anyways! I have created my own code which solved my task, have a look if you wish :)

Answer (score 0):

rotation - my existing dataframe (161X61)
rot- my new dataframe (161X60)

```
arr = np.zeros((9821, 1))
rot = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=range(0, 9821))
for i in range(0, 9821):
    if i==0:
        rot.iloc[i, 0] = (rotation.iloc[i, 0]+rotation.iloc[i+1, 0])/2
    elif ((i%61)==0):
        rot.iloc[i-1, 0] = (rotation.iloc[i, 0]+rotation.iloc[i+1, 0])/2
        rot.iloc[i, 0] = 'del'
    else:
        if ((i==9820)):
            rot.iloc[i, 0] = 'del'
            break
        rot.iloc[i, 0]=rotation.iloc[i+1, 0]
rot.columns = ['alpha']
rot = rot[~rot['alpha'].isin(['del'])]
rot.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
rot
```